# Setting Style of underlying TextViews in style.xml

Tags: android, styles, textview, themes

How is it possible to set the Style of a TextView Child of a LinearLayout via style. Something like this:

```
<style name="MyLinearayoutStyle" parent="MyParentStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/mybackground</item>
    <item name="android:padding>5dp</item>
    // Here i need to define my textview style
</style>


<style name="MyTextViewStyle> parent="AnotherParentStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

I tried android:TextAppearance and android:textStyle, but this didnt work.

Comment: inflate your `TextView` ;)

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103894/overriding-referenced-style-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inflate your `TextView` for example:

```
*textview.xml*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
 style="@+style/MyLinearayoutStyle"
 />
```

and

`activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview,(parent view), true);`

Comment: Thats what im doing right now. Hoped there is a way i can set it for every childview without inflating every single view one by one.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, than I dont know if theres a other solution ;)

Answer (score 8):

Change the theme definition ((stored in res/values/styles.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>   
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">    
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyDefaultTextAppearance</item> 
</style>    
     <style name="MyDefaultTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">    
     <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>     
    <item name="android:textColor">#333</item>    
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>   
    </style> 
    </resources>
```

Comment: This sets the same textappearance for every TextView in the Theme. I want to set the Appearance for only some childs.